# problem with connecting with my netstick on linux platform to internet

Tags: internet-connection, ubuntu-10.10

I instilled ubuntu few days and everything is working just fine except few problems.

My main problem is that I can't my net stick Novatel Ovation MC950D USB HSUPA. I got Asus K40IN series.
My computer recognise the usb and i even found the provider of my connection. but it shows me "disconnected".
Maybe I need to download certain drivers (I found few articles with instruction but didn't have any success with the instructions).

Also I got another problem (maybe they are related) when i turn on my computer i get 2 messages before ubuntu start running:
"modeprobe: no such directory and some directory name with lib"

Thank you very much if you can help me!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this [quick guide](http://quilombo.wordpress.com/2008/01/21/modem-usb-35g-novatel-ovation-mc950d-in-ubuntulinux/) can help you, if I understood it right, it was done using this [manual](http://www4.sprint.com/pcsbusiness/downloads/Sprint_Mobile_Broadband_Setup_Guide.pdf).